# How to view without vertices

Tags: vertices

[image][image]

Hi there, so I've been sculpting a face and I wanted to pull back and take a look at it, but I realized I have no idea how to turn off all the vertices and edges, someone please help me out.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett he is in object mode already.

Comment: @EricXue Thanks! this mostly helped. wireframe was already unchecked, but I went ahead and set it to 0 as well and that got rid of most of it, but there's still some showing where I sculpted most recently. I'll add a picture to the orginal question.

Answer (score 1):

You might have checked "Wireframe" in the Viewport Overlays menu by accident. Seeing that you are already in object mode and have switched to solid view, this could be the problem.

[image]